# Terraform: Adding server logging to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm getting an error in my Terraform scripts when attempting to add logging to two buckets. These are part of one of my modules, and I've successfully used them before. I've come back to deploy a new environment...and now it's not working.

I'm getting the following error:

> module.dev2_environment.module.portal.aws_s3_bucket.portal_bucket: 1 error occurred:
>           * aws_s3_bucket.portal_bucket: Error putting S3 logging: InvalidTargetBucketForLogging: You must give the log-delivery group
>   WRITE and READ_ACP permissions to the target bucket
>           status code: 400, request id: 51AB42EFCACC9924, host id: nYCUxjHZE+xTisA1xG5syLTKVN/Rtwu8z3xF+O9GAPMdC2yGcafP4uwDURUGKd9Lx1SD8aHTcEI=

I'm executing via CLI, with Admin credentials. No code changes were made between the working state and the error. Any ideas on what could have changed? Syntax? AWS config someplace?

Terraform 11.14 and aws provider 2.16

Log bucket:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "logs_bucket" {
  bucket = "XYZ-${var.env}-cdnlogs"
  acl    = "log-delivery-write"
  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        sse_algorithm = "AES256"
      }
    }
  }
  tags {
    Finance     = "dev_env"
    Environment = "${var.env}"
  }
}
```

Target Bucket:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "portal_bucket" {
  bucket = "XYZ-${var.env}-portal"
  acl    = "private"
  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        sse_algorithm = "AES256"
      }
    }
  }
  logging {
    target_bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.logs_bucket.id}"
    target_prefix = "logs/portal/"
  }
  website {
    index_document = "index.html"
    error_document = "index.html"
  }
  // Needed to allow logos to be uploaded the "Portal"
  cors_rule {
    allowed_headers = ["*"]
    allowed_methods = ["GET", "HEAD", "PUT", "POST"]
    allowed_origins = ["*"]
    max_age_seconds = 3000
  }
  tags {
    Finance     = "dev_env"
    Environment = "${var.env}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the values of your `log-delivery-write` ACL to allow Logging -> Read and Logging Write. As well as Read bucket permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is here
`logging {
    target_bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.**logs_bucket**.id}"
    target_prefix = "logs/portal/"
  }`

It should be 
`logging {
    **target_bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.portal_bucket.id}"**
    target_prefix = "logs/portal/"
  }`

Comment: The target bucket should definitely be the logs_bucket and not the portal_bucket (which is the source). What you are proposing would be to store the access logs in the same bucket it is logging access to, thus creating an infinite loop. See https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-server-access-logs-same-bucket and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/enable-server-access-logging.html

Answer (score 0):

The `logging` argument of `aws_s3_bucket` has been deprecated. From [the docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket.html):

> The logging attribute is deprecated. See aws_s3_bucket_logging for examples with logging enabled.

The new resource is [s3_bucket_logging](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_logging):

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_logging" "some-name" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.id

  target_bucket = "log_destination_bucket"
  target_prefix = aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.id
}
```

In my setup I have a single bucket to store the Server Access Logs of all my bucekts, and I use the source bucket's name in the `target_prefix` to keep logs organized in subfolders.